# Laravel, getting deep relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure:

> 'buildings' have many 'blocks' which have many 'units' which have many
>   'tenants'

I need to get a list of all tenants that live in a building.

Laravel provides hasMany and hasManyThrough commands that help you get collections of models which have direct relationship or are related through a single intermediate table but what if you want to get related elements of two, three, or any levels deep?

What is the proper way to achieve this using Laravel/Eloquent?

Comment: Use [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

Comment: Or just use a series of `JOIN`s. But what have _you_ tried?

Comment: Try reading the Laravel documentation before randomly reaching out without any hint of an attempt.

Comment: @devk, whereHas will get you only two levels deep, in this example will get a building's units. I dont think there is a way to chain whereHas statements.

Comment: @fubar, what I have tried is _ugly_ and I didn't want replies to be based on that. I am wondering of what is the proper laravel/eloquent way of achieving this

Comment: You can nest `whereHas` statements.

Comment: @developernator, ofcourse I did but it is not helpful in this specific case or I have missed it, if you know where to look please share your wisdom

Comment: @devk, could you please share an example?

Comment: If you posted your code I could write an example, but I'm not going to google it for you, no.

Comment: @devk, there is no code to post since I couldn't find a way to do it using Eloquent. If you did google it though you'll see that it a problem a lot of people are facing and no clear answer is ever given, even in Laravel's documentation. fubar, has posted a very nice answer below, it is basically running the query instead of using Eloquent commands....but it does work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find all the tenants in a given building, the easiest method would be to use `JOIN` clauses.

I have assumed all of your relationships are `hasMany` inversed by `belongsTo`.

```
$tenants = Tenant::select('tenants.*')
    ->join('units', 'units.id', '=', 'tenant.unit_id')
    ->join('blocks', 'blocks.id', '=', 'units.block_id')
    ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', '=', 'blocks.building_id')
    ->where('buildings.id', 123)
    ->get();
```

If this is something you'll use more than once, then I'd suggest creating a query scope on your `Tenant` model.

```
class Tenant extends Eloquent
{
    // ...

    public function scopeInBuilding($query, $buildingId)
    {
        return $query->select('tenants.*')
            ->join('units', 'units.id', '=', 'tenant.unit_id')
            ->join('blocks', 'blocks.id', '=', 'units.block_id')
            ->join('buildings', 'buildings.id', '=', 'blocks.building_id')
            ->where('buildings.id', $buildingId);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
$tenants = Tenant::inBuilding(123)->get();
```

Answer (score 16):

There is no native relationship for this case.

I created a `HasManyThrough` relationship with unlimited levels: [Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep)

After the installation, you can use it like this:

```php
class Building extends Model {
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentHasManyDeep\HasRelationships;

    public function tenants() {
        return $this->hasManyDeep(Tenant::class, [Block::class, Unit::class]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Jonas, thank you so much for this it seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I ended up putting a foreign key for building into the tenant table which was what I was trying to avoid. I will give your solution a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you want to do is Nested eager loading. Like accessing relation with in relation:

E.g.
If you have posts which have comments and comments have replies and
you want all posts with comments and replies of the comments:

```
$posts = Post::with('comment.reply')->get();
```

Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Most appropriate answer I can see here

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to calculate it.

1. At first, you can define a has many relationship between buildings & blocks.
2. Find tenants for each blocks of a building using a has many Through relation among blocks & tenants using units.

Comment: this is kind of what I am currently doing but it gets very ugly as relationships get deeper

Answer (score 0):

First define relationship in respective model (one to one / one to many)
and then can retrieve that relationship data using with helper
E.g.;

```php
$users = User::with('podcasts')->get();
// here podcasts is the defined relationship in user model
```

Comment: Hey HCK, thanks for the reply but this will only get me one level deep, I need to access data whose tables do not have a direct relationship with each other.

Comment: @paishin lol i've just edited the question. The answer comes from kshitij. Hope you solved it.