# How can I deep relationships with belongsToMany and belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I got stuck with this relational structure:

I am using staudenmeir package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

I have **Group** which is in  `belongsToMany` with **ConstructionProduct** which is `belongsToMany` with **Project**

I need to access **Project** in **Group** Model.

My model looks something like this:

```
class Group extends Model
{

    public function constructionProduct()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany(ConstructionProduct::class,'construction_product_details',
            'product_group_id', 'construction_product_id');
    }


}


class ConstructionProduct extends Model {

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class,'construction_product_projects','construction_product_id','project_id');
    }

}
```

My relationship looks like:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasManyDeep(
        Project::class,
        ['construction_product_details', ConstructionProduct::class, 'construction_product_projects'],
        ['product_group_id', 'construction_product_id', 'id'],
        ['id', 'construction_product_id', 'project_id']
    );
}
```

> Error: Unknown column 'construction_product.project_id

Help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel, getting deep relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808554/laravel-getting-deep-relationships)

Comment: You seem to be making these relationships very complicated. Does `construction_product` table have a `project_id` column?